# Is this the right way of handling command line arguments?

Tags: python

```
ask_username = True
ask_password = True
ask_message = True
ask_number = True

def Usage():
    print '\t-h, --help:  View help'
    print '\t-u, --username: Username'
    print '\t-p, --password: Password'
    print '\t-n, --number: numbber to send the sms'
    print '\t-m, --message: Message to send'
    sys.exit(1)


opts, args = getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'u:p:m:n:h',["username=","password=","message=","number=","help"])

print opts, args
for o,v in opts:
    if o in ("-h", "--help"):
        Usage()
    elif o in ("-u", "--username"):
        username = v
        ask_username = False
    elif o in ("-p", "--password"):
        passwd = v
        ask_password = False
    elif o in ("-m", "--message"):
        message = v
        ask_message = False
    elif o in ("-n", "--number"):
        number = v
        ask_number = False

#Credentials taken here
if ask_username: username = raw_input("Enter USERNAME: ")
if ask_password: passwd = getpass()
if ask_message: message = raw_input("Enter Message: ")
if ask_number: number = raw_input("Enter Mobile number: ")
```

I dont think it is, because I am using 4 objects just for checking if command line argument was provided...

> Guide me with the best way of doing
>   it..

Comment: If you're using getopt, always use getopt.gnu_getopt, not getopt.getopt.

Comment: `sys.exit(1)` indicates failure (that's what the 1 means). If you had printed the message due to an error in the options, 2 would be the right error code. Since you are exiting successfully, you would just use `sys.exit()`, which exits with 0 to indicate success. (Of course, you would not do this at all because you want to use optparse or something like it.) Also, always start your function names with lowercase letters.

Comment: U r right. I used it wrongly. Thanx

Comment: That's how all "modern" applications handle commandline parsing.  Older systems (and ones stuck in the past, *cough* FreeBSD) won't accept eg. "ls /tmp -l" with arguments at the end, which is enough to drive a user to insanity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might find that the [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module is useful -- it allows you to specify which options you want and their types and help text, then to parse the options and get all the results back.

It also auto-generates the help output for you, so you only have to maintain your options in one place.

Comment: argparse is more powerful, IMO. But, optparse is tried and true, and very widely available.

Answer (score 1):

argparse is another option if optparse does not cover all your needs

[optparse vs argparse](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/argparse-vs-optparse.html)

Comment: argparse will be added to the standard library in 2.7 and 3.2, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

While the right thing is to use optparse, some comments on the code -- as presented -- are in order.

The four condition flags (ask_username, ask_password, ask_message, ask_number) are useless.

Consider your post-condition for any one of these four items (they're all the same)

```
(in_args AND variable_set) OR (not in_args AND prompt AND variable_set)
```

You're really doing something like this.

```
username= None 

# Pre Condition: username is not set to a useful value

# ... use `optparse` to parse options ... 
username = options.username 

# Post Condition: username may be None if no option provided
# or username may be set if an option was provided.

if username is None: # it's not set to a useful value
    # ... prompt to get a value for username ... 

assert username is not None
```

You don't need any flags when you have default values that are more useful.

Comment: This is also an option.. But, i should better use optparse as suggested by others.

Comment: The point is that the core algorithm has too many variables.  `optparse` won't eliminate the mis-use of spurious "flags" to duplication conditions that can be described more simply.

Answer (score 1):

So far **optparse** has fitted all my needs.